# Repetitive questions

Tags: discussion

I feel like I see the same questions all the time in the community I am most involved with (`Salesforce`). But I am sure it happens in all, or most.

Most of the time I ignore them or flag them as already answered. But, more and more, I am wanting to to put a sarcastic `lmgtfy` link on them.

I guess I am just curious for what is the best/accepted way for a community to deal with this? Rather than answering the same'-ish' question over and over again? Which seems to be the norm.. Seems like we are getting bogged down rather than cleaning up as we go???

Comment: Got to admit now I am more active in answering I do feel like there should be an rtfm link to the help given the number of repetitive and poor quality questions coming in.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If they're new users, I believe it's important to welcome them to our community while also taking the time to educate them on how our community works and what we expect of them. That means point them to "[help]" and "how to ask a good question", letting them know that the "links to the right" probably have the answer to their question if they'd just take the time to look or use the "search link above and to the right".

We were all new to SF.SE at some time or another. Hopefully, someone was kind enough to us or else we witnessed them being kind to someone else. For most of us, I'd hope it was that kind of experience that helped us learn to use the forum, helped create a positive environment for everyone and caused our members to want to hang around and contribute. I hope we'll see that continue as Salesforce grows and this forum continues to grow along with it.

Comment: Great Answer !!